# Combinations with multiple containers of varying sizes

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinations

If you know what this kind of problem is called, let me know (unless you actually know the answer to the question).

If I have a set Z of objects, is there an algorithm for diving them up between a bunch of containers (each holding a certain number of objects)?

To slightly complicate the problem, let's assume the set of objects we start with has a subset X. There are X containers, and each container must hold a single element of X, in addition to other objects (if it has room).

The best way I can think of doing this currently is looking at the disjunction of Z and X, let's call it Y. Then we can generate the z choose x combinations, and then expand that out for all possible combinations of x.

**Example:**
The actual problem is basically generating all events in a space. Suppose we have two event triggers (X) and 2 event arguments (Y), where Z = X U Y. Each event must have a trigger, and it can have 0...N arguments (depending on the type of event, but that isn't important for now. A trigger can also be an argument. Clearly, in this situation we can have a single event with one trigger and 3 arguments (one of which is the second trigger)

Our event space is as follows (Trigger[Arguments], + indicates a new event):

```
X1[] + X2[]
X1[Y1] + X2[]
X1[Y2] + X2[]
X1[] + X2[Y1]
X1[] + X2[Y2]
X1[Y1] + X2[Y2]
X1[Y2] + X2[Y1]
X1[X2]
X1[X2,Y1]
X1[X2,Y2]
X1[X2,Y1,Y2]
X2[X1]
X2[X1,Y1]
X2[X1,Y2]
X2[X1,Y1,Y2]
```

I'm pretty sure that's all the combinations.

**Update:**
After thinking a bit more about the problem, I have a few thoughts on constraints and stuff: Rules for creating "events":
1) There is an event for every trigger, and every event must have a trigger
2) Event must have > 0 arguments
3) Events cannot share arguments
4) Triggers can be used as arguments

For a brute force solution, perhaps one could generate all permutations of the triggers + events and then eliminate results that don't match the above 4 rules, and treat the ordering as grouping of events?

Thanks for any problem names or ideas!

Comment: X1[Y1, Y2] + X2[] is not valid? I am unable to decipher your description involving "event triggers" and "event arguments". Are you able to provide a more explicit description?

Comment: It is, I missed that one (and at least 3 others that are similar). The 'event triggers' vs 'arguments' are names that come from the full problem I'm trying to solve, which is extracting protein interactions from unstructured text (Medline abstracts).

Comment: If you had more Xs and Ys, would you have things that looked like X1[X2,X3,Y1] and X1[X2,X3] + X4[X5,X6,Y1]?

Comment: Yes, but eventually some of the x's need to contain a y. I'm going to implement some sort of recursive powerset solution I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm:

```
For all nonempty subsets Triggers of X:
    For all maps from (X \ Triggers) to X:
        For all maps from Y to (X union {None}):
            print the combination, where an assignment of y in Y to None means y is omitted
```

In Python:

```
def assignments(xs, ys):
    asgns = [[]]
    for x in xs:
        asgns1 = []
        for y in ys:
            for asgn in asgns:
                asgn1 = asgn[:]
                asgn1.append((x, y))
                asgns1.append(asgn1)
        asgns = asgns1
    return asgns

def combinations(xs, ys):
    xroleasgns = assignments(xs, ('argument', 'trigger'))
    for xroleasgn in xroleasgns:
        triggers = [x for (x, role) in xroleasgn if role == 'trigger']
        if (xs or ys) and not triggers:
            continue
        xargs = [x for (x, role) in xroleasgn if role == 'argument']
        for xargasgn in assignments(xargs, triggers):
            for yargasgn in assignments(ys, [None] + triggers):
                d = dict((x, []) for x in triggers)
                for xarg, t in xargasgn:
                    d[t].append(xarg)
                for yarg, t in yargasgn:
                    if t is not None:
                        d[t].append(yarg)
                print ' + '.join('%s[%s]' % (t, ','.join(args)) for (t, args) in d.iteritems())


"""
>>> assign.combinations(['X1','X2'],['Y1','Y2'])
X1[X2]
X1[X2,Y1]
X1[X2,Y2]
X1[X2,Y1,Y2]
X2[X1]
X2[X1,Y1]
X2[X1,Y2]
X2[X1,Y1,Y2]
X2[] + X1[]
X2[] + X1[Y1]
X2[Y1] + X1[]
X2[] + X1[Y2]
X2[] + X1[Y1,Y2]
X2[Y1] + X1[Y2]
X2[Y2] + X1[]
X2[Y2] + X1[Y1]
X2[Y1,Y2] + X1[]


"""
```

Comment: That's really nice, thanks. After considering the original problem I realized there were a lot of things I could change/simplify, but I think they are best used as filters on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my java implementation over9000's solution to the original problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList xs = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList ys = new ArrayList();
    xs.add("X1");
    xs.add("X2");
    ys.add("Y1");
    ys.add("Y2");

    combinations(xs,ys);
}

private static void combinations(ArrayList xs, ArrayList ys) {
    ArrayList def = new ArrayList();
    def.add("argument");
    def.add("trigger");

    ArrayList<ArrayList> xroleasgns = assignments(xs, def);
    for(ArrayList xroleasgn:xroleasgns){
        // create triggers list
        ArrayList triggers = new ArrayList();
        for(Object o:xroleasgn){
            Pair p = (Pair)o;
            if("trigger".equals(p.b.toString()))
                triggers.add(p.a);              
        }

        if((xs.size()>0 || ys.size()>0) && triggers.size()==0)
            continue;

        // create xargs list
        ArrayList xargs = new ArrayList();
        for(Object o:xroleasgn){
            Pair p = (Pair)o;
            if("argument".equals(p.b.toString()))
                xargs.add(p.a);             
        }

        // Get combinations!
        for(ArrayList xargasgn:assignments(xargs,triggers)){
            ArrayList yTriggers = new ArrayList(triggers);
            yTriggers.add(null);

            for(ArrayList yargasgn:assignments(ys,yTriggers)){

                // d = dict((x, []) for x in triggers)
                HashMap<Object,ArrayList> d = new HashMap<Object,ArrayList>();
                for(Object x:triggers)
                    d.put(x, new ArrayList());

                for(Object o:xargasgn){
                    Pair p = (Pair)o;
                    d.get(p.b).add(p.a);    
                }

                for(Object o:yargasgn){
                    Pair p = (Pair)o;
                    if(p.b!=null){
                        d.get(p.b).add(p.a);
                    }
                }


                for(Entry<Object, ArrayList> e:d.entrySet()){
                    Object t = e.getKey();
                    ArrayList args = e.getValue();
                    System.out.print(t+"["+args.toString()+"]"+"+");
                }
                System.out.println();                   

            }
        }
    }
}

private static ArrayList<ArrayList> assignments(ArrayList xs, ArrayList def) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList> asgns = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    asgns.add(new ArrayList()); //put an initial empty arraylist
    for(Object x:xs){
        ArrayList asgns1 = new ArrayList();
        for(Object y:def){
            for(ArrayList<Object> asgn:asgns){
                ArrayList asgn1 = new ArrayList();
                asgn1.addAll(asgn);
                asgn1.add(new Pair(x,y));
                asgns1.add(asgn1);
            }
        }
        asgns = asgns1;
    }
    return asgns;
}
```